# Spring integration outbound-gateway want to use URL as dynamic like

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

spring Integration,in outbound-gateway want to use URL as dynamic like

```
    <bean id="requestValues"    class="com.src.model.RequestValues"/>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
                request-channel="reqChannel" url="${UrlValue}"
                http-method="${reqmethod}" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"  header-mapper="headerMapper"
                charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="responseChannel"  >
            <int-http:uri-variable name="UrlValue" expression="#{requestValues.getUrl()}" />
           <int-http:uri-variable name="reqmethod" expression="#{requestValues.getReqMethod()}" />
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Here Requestvalues is simple POJO 
it like

```
@Data
public class Requestvalues {

    public String Url;
    public String reqMethod;

}
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6ea2bc93' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.ExpressionFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'uriVariableExpressions' with key [url]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6ea2bc93': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.config.ExpressionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expressionString must not be empty or null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set meta data like URL or http method as headers. You can even use Spring EL when setting the header, f.e.

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="url" value="${url.base}/reports/"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

and then use an expression for the outbound gateway

```
 <int-http:outbound-gateway id='httpGateway'
 url-expression="headers['url']"
...
  />
```

Comment: `Accept` and `method` are not part of the URI so can't use `uri-variable`s.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but small correction here Accept & content-type are working fine, only thing want to make URL as dynamic, that URL am creating in java code based on certain conditions

Comment: Mmmm thanks appreciate your response leave it that,here my doubt is how to make my URL and http-method as dynamic, which has to come from POJO

Answer (score 0):

The `http-method` is not part of the URI; it does not support or use `uri-variables`.

Use `http-method-expression="payload.reqMethod"` instead.

Similarly, `Accept` is not part of the uri - set the Accept header in the outbound message, it will be mapped.

**EDIT**

You are confusing runtime expressions with bean declaration expressions and, as I said, you need to use method expression if you want a runtime method selection.

However, since you are using a bean for your `Requestvalues` you don't need runtime expressions at all.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
            request-channel="reqChannel" url="#{requestValues.getUrl()}"
            http-method=""#{requestValues.getReqMethod()}" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"  header-mapper="headerMapper"
            charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="responseChannel"  >
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

If you want to select the method and url at runtime, based on the message, you would use something like...

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
            request-channel="reqChannel" url="${UrlValue}"
            http-method-expression="headers['method']" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"  header-mapper="headerMapper"
            charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="responseChannel"  >
        <int-http:uri-variable name="UrlValue" expression="headers['url']" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Where the headers are set dynamically somewhere upstream, or

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
            request-channel="reqChannel" url="${UrlValue}"
            http-method-expression="@requestValues.getReqMethod()" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"  header-mapper="headerMapper"
            charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="responseChannel"  >
        <int-http:uri-variable name="UrlValue" expression="@requestValues.getUrl()" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Notice the use of `@` to refer to beans in runtime expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but small correction here Accept & content-type are working fine, only thing want to make URL as dynamic, that URL am creating in java code based in certain conditions

Comment: `<int-http:uri-variable name="Accept" expression="application/json" />` - the `Accept` and `content type` headers are not set from an `uri-variable`; you must be setting the header someplace else, perhaps in a transformer.

Comment: Hmm fine  Gray,now i modified my question,again am repeating my question want to make my URL & http-method as generic

Comment: You are mixing runtime and initialization-time expressions; see my edit.

Comment: That is not an answer - edit your question instead.  The first one seems to indicate your `requestValues` is not set up correctly; the same thing (for the URL) for the second one; you need to show ALL your code.

Comment: Thanks lot Gary !!! got it,but when i try with this  url="${UrlValue}" url value is coming like "$https://docs.spring.io", so i removed it and am using url-expression="@requestData.getCompleteUrl()"